# Programmatically insert field collection of Phone fields

Tags: entities

I have a profile2 profile type. In profile type i have created the collection for storing the information of form fields.

I have used the [phone](http://drupal.org/project/phone) module to create the phone number fields.
This collection contains the two phone number fields, one for office and one for mobile.

So my scenario is give below

```
--Profile type

--- Field collection to store the phone numbers

---- Two fields to store  phone numbers
    1. field_office_phone
    2. field_office_mobile
```

Now i want to save the data of the field programmatically. 
I have used below snippet from [here](http://drupal.org/node/1477216) to create and save the field collection programmatically.
In the given below code **company** is my profile2 profile bundle.

```
module_load_include('inc', 'field_collection', 'field_collection.pages');
  // Load the profile we're adding the field to
  $profile_entity = profile2_load_by_user($account, 'company');

  // Define the values of the new field
  $values = array();
  $values['field_name'] = 'field_contact_number'; // field collection name
  $values['field_office_phone'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#value']['number'] = 1234;
  $values['field_office_mobile'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#value']['number'] = 12374;

  // Create the field collection entry and associate it with the profile
  $field_entity = entity_create('field_collection_item', $values);
  $field_entity->setHostEntity('profile2', $profile_entity);
  $field_entity->save();
```

The above code snippet only creates field but it is not storign the values in the field.
I am not getting the reason why it is not setting the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works fine for user entities under Drupal 7:

```
  $values['field_office_phone'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['number'] = '0412345678';
  $values['field_office_phone'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['country_codes'] = 'au';
```

Adapt countrycode to your user's country.
I don't think I'm using Profile2 and there are multiple different modules that implement phone number fields. My server has cck_phone-7.x-1.x-dev installed.